# Android - UnknownHost exception when parsing an RSS feed

Tags: java, android, dns, rss

I want to parse an rss feed from an android application. Everything related to parsing the RSS feed itself is done (using SAX), however I get an exception regarding the name resolution of the feed's url.

This is the line causing the exception:

```
feedUrl = "http://blog.jonathanbenoudiz.com/feed/"
feedUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException:

So I started investigating my `/etc/resolv.conf` file and set the nameserver to the dns server of my ISP. Pinging `blog.jonathanbenoudiz.com` works, but `http://blog.jonathanbenoudiz.com` and `blog.jonathanbenoudiz.com/feed` don't work (unknown host).

How am I actually supposed to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: How about INTERNET permission in manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the INTERNET permission to your manifest file.

You have to add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml